# Converting columns to rows (UNPIVOT) in hiveql

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, unpivot

I have a table with a structure like this:

```
column1, column2, column3, X1, X2, X3, X4
A1,      A2,      A3,      5,  6,  1,  4
```

I would like to convert this into

```
column1, column2, column3, Key, Value 
 A1,      A2,      A3,      X1,  5
 A1,      A2,      A3,      X2,  6 
 A1,      A2,      A3,      X3,  1
 A1,      A2,      A3,      X4   4
```

I was able to do this already using 4 queries stitched together with "UNION ALL", but since the table is huge and each select translates into a lengthy map-reduce, using UNION makes the query takes N times the time it should ideally take. Where N is number of columns to pivot.

I tried exploring the explode() pre-defined UDTF, but I am not able to work it in this example. I tried something like the following, but am not able to make the syntax work.

```
select column1, column2, column3, explode(Map('X1':X1, 'X2':X2, ..))
```

Can someone please point out exactly how to make this work?? I am guessing I could roll my own UDTF, but am hoping this is something pretty standard?

**EDIT:**
There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621970) on stackoverflow where something similar was asked, but the formulation is convoluted and in my opinion the wrong answer is currently marked as the correct answer. I think this question is more succint and to the point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoops, posted this in a hurry it seems. I have the answer. Posting it here for others who might find this useful.
Here is the correct syntax to deal with map and explode to achieve this.

```
select column1, column2, column3, m_key, m_val from
    (select column1, column2, column3, map("X1", X1, "X2", X2, "X3", X3, "X4", X4) as map1
    from table1) as t1
lateral view explode(map1) xyz as m_key, m_val
```

Comment: This has been asked and answered numerous times.