# SQL: Duplicate rows based on columns

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Name   | Math   | English  | Arts
----------------------------------------
Brad   | 87     | 65       | 90
Julie  | 91     | 88       | 92
```

And I want to get:

```
Name  | Grade
--------------
Brad  | 87
Brad  | 65
Brad  | 90
Julie | 91
Julie | 88
Julie | 92
```

What's the simplest way to do that using SQL/Hive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.

```
select name,math as Grade from your_table
union all
select name,English as Grade from your_table
union all
select name,Arts as Grade from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  t.name, 
  CASE rows.col_name
    WHEN 'Math' THEN t.Math
    WHEN 'English' THEN t.**math** 
    WHEN 'Arts' THEN t.Arts
  end as Grade
from the_table t, 
     (select 'Math' as col_name
      union all 
      select 'English' as col_name
      union all 
      select 'Arts' as col_name) rows
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `unpivot`:

```
SELECT X.Name, X.Grade
FROM your_table s
UNPIVOT
(
  Grade
  FOR Subject in (Maths, English, Arts)
) X;
```

If you want to have the subject in the result add `X.Subject` into the select statement.

Comment: I can get ot to run on Hive, are you sure it supports `UNPIVOT`? I also assume it's `as` after `your_table`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too clear about Hive. I answered it with respect to solving it using SQL.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621970/hive-unpivot-functionality-in-hive) has an unpivot in Hive example which may help.