# how to convert columns into rows in HIVE

Tags: hive

I have a table in HIVE which looks like this

```
cust_1,month_1, f1,f2,f3 
cust_1,month_2, f2,f3,f4   
cust_2,month_1, f1,f5,f4
```

I would like to convert it in the following format

```
cust_1,month_1, f1
cust_1,month_1, f2   
cust_1,month_1, f3
```

....

How that is possible in HIVE?

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff.  Hive doesn't have pivot/unpivot, so just `select cust, month, f1 union all select cust, month, f2...`.

Comment: @Andrew `UNION ALL` to pivot data in Hive is inefficient.  If you want to go wide to long, you create key value pairs and explode.  Its outlined in the below answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive - Unpivot functionality in hive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621970/hive-unpivot-functionality-in-hive)

Answer (score 3):

you can use this sql:

```
select col1, col2, value 
     from orig_table lateral view explode(array(col3,col4,col5)) orig_table_alias as value;
```