# UN-Pivot in HIVE

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am working with a HIVE table and have a data like below:

```
id  channel pkg_1_sk    pkg_1_nm    pkg_1_prod_1_sk pkg_1_prod_1_nm pkg_1_prod_2_sk pkg_1_prod_2_nm pkg_2_sk    pkg_2_nm    pkg_2_prod_1_sk pkg_2_prod_1_nm pkg_2_prod_2_sk pkg_2_prod_2_nm
abc XYZ      1          Package-1   1               Prod-1          2               Prod-2           2          Package-2   3                 Prod-3         2               Prod-2
```

and I want the data like below:

```
id  channel pkg_sk  prod_sk
abc XYZ     1       1
abc XYZ     1       2
abc XYZ     2       3
abc XYZ     2       2
```

Is there any way I can achieve the result without using UNION ALL. The source table is huge and UNION ALL will cause a performance issue.

Comment: Did you check this **2nd** answer to another similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/32622625/7998591

Comment: IMHO If the data were in loadable format, DDL+DML, the chances someone will help are much better